# Flashing 2 groups of messages in 2 different places using Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to [flash](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/flashing/) 2 different sets of messages in 2 different parts of a webpage using Flask.

On my webpage I have code to get flashed messages for one set of messages:

```
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul class=flashes>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
```

How can I create another instance of this and send an entirely different group of messages to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you linked to has a solution:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/flashing/#filtering-flash-messages

> Filtering Flash Messages New in version 0.9.
>
> Optionally you can pass a list of categories which filters the results
>   of get_flashed_messages(). This is useful if you wish to render each
>   category in a separate block.

So for example, you could flash messages like this:

```
flash('category one flash message', 'category1')
flash('category two flash message', 'category2')
```

Then in your template:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["category1"]) %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["category2"]) %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```